# Client ghosted after delivering results, no payment

Tags: difficult-client, payments

About 20 days ago, I got a job. I don't know what country he is.
I worked harder and almost done. He wanted to see the result.
So I sent my work data.
He sent me some issues.
So I corrected the issues.
But he was so unhappy that I didn't worked perfect.
I thought that issues can happen normally. But the client didn't paid.
What can I do in that situation?

Comment: Always demand from your client upfront payment for any project, else is almost 100% of chances from you don't get paid, it's what I've heard from any freelancer which I've talked with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have given everything away, there might be very little you can do.

All you can do now is hope that the client for some reason returns.

If that happens, you have some leverage you **MUST** use. This is obviously a client where good faith is not enough - so you must negotiate a working process you can live with. This will typically involve partial deliveries and not performing more work until payment is received.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you had to send, I want to know what would you do?

Comment: What do you want to send? A request for payment?

Answer (score 2):

In a freelancing business like I did and some new business that needs an order before working on it (custom project), I do usually asking payment upfront.

In your situation Mr.Morsor's answer is right, there is little you can do and almost to none because you don't know the person is, you don't know how to contact him.

If an unknown client comes to contacting you only online, you never know his real name, his place, etc. please asking the money upfront.

In general manners, the money up front could be:

- 100%
- 50% upfront, 50% until the project is done.
- Progress upfront: 25% upfront, sending the data for inspection 25%, revision 25%, and the last 25% if it's done.

Never send any data that 100% completed without money in your hands. In speaking in general, you can send the client not completed project, until the money in your hand.